# Share Wi-Fi connection over Ethernet?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a laptop with WiFi and a PC with Ethernet.

On my laptop I connect to the Internet with a broadband connection on a Wi-Fi network (Wi-Fi does not have Internet Access directly).

Can I share this Wi-Fi network from my Laptop with Ethernet cable to connect PC to Internet with Broadband connection on PC?

Both have Windows 7.

Comment: A better title may be "How can I make my PC become a hotspot.

Comment: @Griffin why would he do that? That's the opposite of what he wants.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed.

1. Go to Control Panel
2. In search, type in "Network Connections"
3. Find one that says "View network connections" under Network and
   Sharing Center.
4. Enter it, and right click on the internet you would like to share and hit "Properties".
5. Go on the Sharing tab, and check "Allow other network users to connect through this Computer's internet connection"
6. Click Ok
7. Plug the ethernet cable into both of the computers and on the one you'd like to connect, it should automatically connect.

But it won't work if you have your wireless connection with a static IP.

Comment: Thanks dude this damn thing was on the tip of my tongue and aggravating the daylights out of me.

Comment: Did it work? If so, tick the tick under the arrow by my post, then you can show others what worked for you.

Comment: Worked for me, i can get internet on my laptop via. Wi-fi - configured ICS on my laptop, then i got internet on my desktop via. eathernet cable directly connected to my laptop.

Comment: One more help, i want to share my laptop internet (got via wi-fi) with my modem( or router) - it has 4 eathernet out ports, so - i can get internet upto 4 desktops. is it posssible?

Answer (score 18):

I have spent countless hours trying to share my internet connection from one desktop (Windows 10, equipped with a Wifi card) to another (not equipped with a Wifi card), and I have finally found a solution that has worked every time for me. I can share from Windows 10 (should work with Win7 too) to any other ethernet equipped device, Windows and Mac. It is bizarre and roundabout, but I haven't seen anyone post anything quite like this so I'm putting it out there anywhere I can.

All you need to do is follow the simple instructions below.

Okay, so:

-﻿Open Internet settings, view network connections

("Change adapter options").

﻿-Right click on your Wifi adapter, go to properties. Go to the sharing tab and disable network sharing if it is enabled.

-Close the properties window, then select your Wifi adapter and your Ethernet.

-Right click and make a network bridge between the two.

-Select the network bridge and disable it.

-Delete the network bridge.

-Right click your Wifi adapter, click properties. Go to the sharing tab and enable sharing again (make sure both boxes are checked).

-Go to the settings tab, make sure all of the boxes are checked except for "Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Protocol".

-If you have online games that use PunkBuster, reinstall PunkBuster.

Any time your network sharing stops working, simply repeat these steps to get it back up and running.

And that's it.﻿ If you've followed all these instructions, it should work. Again, I don't know how or why, but this has worked 100% of the time for me. Hopefully this saves some people a headache!

Comment: This worked for me (April 2020)

Comment: Worked for me! Win10 build 10.0.19041

Comment: I tried the answer from Lewes first but it stopped working. Then I tried this, and it worked (Windows 10 --> Ubuntu 16)

Comment: Worked for me, whereas accepted answer didn't. (Dec 2020). Needed to have an ethernet connection to a PINE 64 board and this worked. :)